# Does "I should get to solving the math problems" mean the same as I should start solving the math problems?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

I should get to solving the math problems.

Does the above sentence mean- I should start solving the math problems?
And is it grammatically correct?

Comment: You are correct about the meaning.  I can't say definitely that is grammatically incorrect, but it is at least not "high English" as it were.

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "High English"?

Comment: I mean that it isn't what the upper class Englishmen would say.  I can't say for sure that it is incorrect, but I wouldn't use it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the sentence is correct, and [you got the meaning right](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/get-to#get-to__2).

There is a nuance: “I should get to doing …” implies that you might have started doing it sooner. It's somewhat intermediate between “I should start doing …” which is neutral, and “I should [get around to doing …](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/get-around-to)”.

It's [rather an American expression](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+to+doing%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cget+to+doing%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cget%20to%20doing%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cget%20to%20doing%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0).

This expresssion is not to be confused with “I should get to do …”, which has a completely different meaning: “I should have the opportunity to do …”.